# Why is my Excel chart generating a legend that doesn't correspond with the pie chart?

Tags: c#, excel-interop, excel-charts

I am generating a basic Excel chart with this code:

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
//add data 
_xlSheet.Cells[11, 11] = "PhooBar";
_xlSheet.Cells[11, 12] = "Student1";
_xlSheet.Cells[11, 13] = "Student2";
_xlSheet.Cells[11, 14] = "Student3";

_xlSheet.Cells[12, 11] = "Term1";
_xlSheet.Cells[12, 12] = "80";
_xlSheet.Cells[12, 13] = "65";
_xlSheet.Cells[12, 14] = "45";

_xlSheet.Cells[13, 11] = "Term2";
_xlSheet.Cells[13, 12] = "78";
_xlSheet.Cells[13, 13] = "72";
_xlSheet.Cells[13, 14] = "60";

_xlSheet.Cells[14, 11] = "Term3";
_xlSheet.Cells[14, 12] = "82";
_xlSheet.Cells[14, 13] = "80";
_xlSheet.Cells[14, 14] = "65";

_xlSheet.Cells[15, 11] = "Term4";
_xlSheet.Cells[15, 12] = "75";
_xlSheet.Cells[15, 13] = "82";
_xlSheet.Cells[15, 14] = "68";

Excel.Range chartRange;

Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)_xlSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(468, 160, 348, 268);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

chartRange = _xlSheet.get_Range("K11", "O15"); // K == 11, O == 15
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlPieExploded;
```

I have a question about controlling the label placement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095872/how-can-i-add-labels-onto-the-pie-pieces-that-are-large-enough-to-contain-them).

Now I want to know why there are four pie pieces but five items on the legend:

[image]

ISTM that the chart engine's legend should match the pie. What's the deal?

Comment: Because your legend 4 items, the purple one will be the "" one..

Comment: Is it not because of this? `_xlSheet.Cells[11, 11] = "";`

Comment: `_xlSheet.Cells[11, 11] = "";` change to say `foo` and you'll get `foo` in your legend...

Comment: Commenting out the assignment to 11,11 changes nothing.

Comment: @Ian: Updated the code to reflect that mod.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon in that case, perhaps you could also post the codes which has the `_xlSheet` and `Excel`, who knows someone could replicate your problem and help you in the direction? Not many use `Interop.Excel` tools I think...

Comment: Anyway, the range K-L-M-N-O is 5 columns and 11 to 15 is 5 rows... But you only have rows from 11 to 14 there. It might be related to the undesired result you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the code to this, the pie and the legend correspond:

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
//add data 
_xlSheet.Cells[12, 11] = "Term1";
_xlSheet.Cells[12, 12] = "80";
_xlSheet.Cells[12, 13] = "65";
_xlSheet.Cells[12, 14] = "45";

_xlSheet.Cells[13, 11] = "Term2";
_xlSheet.Cells[13, 12] = "78";
_xlSheet.Cells[13, 13] = "72";
_xlSheet.Cells[13, 14] = "60";

_xlSheet.Cells[14, 11] = "Term3";
_xlSheet.Cells[14, 12] = "82";
_xlSheet.Cells[14, 13] = "80";
_xlSheet.Cells[14, 14] = "65";

_xlSheet.Cells[15, 11] = "Term4";
_xlSheet.Cells[15, 12] = "75";
_xlSheet.Cells[15, 13] = "82";
_xlSheet.Cells[15, 14] = "68";

Excel.Range chartRange;

//return;

Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)_xlSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(468, 160, 348, 268);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

chartRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[12, 11], _xlSheet.Cells[15, 14]];
```

I changed from "get_Range" to the more efficient and easier-to-grok "Range[]" and there is now a 1:1 correspondency between the pie pieces and the legend:

[image]